# Transferring Texture Across Classes

Tags: c#, class, xna, texture2d

(Resizing and `LoadContent()`)

I want to separate textures by having my Title Screen be in a class and call on it when needed. This would help with neatness but I have only been working with moving sprites across classes and `Texture2D` is not the same.

I have an image 1024X768 and am calling on the image in `Title Screen.cs` and want to be able to use `LoadContent()` in `Title Screen.cs` to load anything with out having to go to Game1.cs to Load the image and come back to `Title Screen.cs`. Using load content in Title Screen.cs will make my code easier to read and understand. It needs to fit the screen as well and is not, I would like to know what function I could use to re size it.

(I have a function now from resizing the image but it is only a manual fix. I must input the correct width of the screen, is there a simple way to check the screen height and width?)

---

**EDIT:** I have now fix the code to be updated to the new version.

I have the normal start up for the main class, Game1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Title_Test
{
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public Game1()
    {
        Title_Screen.Content = Content;
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        Title_Screen.Load();
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        Title_Screen.Draw(spriteBatch);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

Title Screen.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Title_Test
{
class Title_Screen
{
    public static ContentManager Content;
    public static Texture2D titleScreenPH;//Texture to be transferred.
    Vector2 TitleScreen = new Vector2(0, 0);

    public static int myWidth = 800;
    public static int myHeight = 480;

    public static void Load()
    {
        titleScreenPH = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\TitleScreenPH");
    }

    static public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(titleScreenPH, new Rectangle(0, 0, myWidth, myHeight), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't follow what you are asking for. You already are supplying the texture to `Title_Screen`. You are not therefore having to reference back to `Game1`. Where does the size come into this? Are you wanting to load different sized textures? Rescale?

Comment: I have added a second paragraph to the question David, hopefully you can understand now, I don't want to call on the texture in Game1 because it will make me have to go back and forth from two classes when I could just have it under one class.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just would have to implement a method 'LoadContent' in your class 'Title_Screen', and provide the 'Content' object as parameter. The you can move the code to load the texture from 'Game1' to 'Title_Screen'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change the drawing size of your sprite just give look to the overloads of the [`Draw()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx) method of the `SpriteBatch` class:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(titleScreenPH, new Rectangle(0, 0, myWidth, myHeight), Color.White);
```

---

**EDIT:**

> I have an image 1024X768 and am calling on the image in Title
>   Screen.cs and want to be able to use LoadContent() in Title Screen.cs
>   to load anything with out having to go to Game1.cs to Load the image
>   and come back to Title Screen.cs. Using load content in Title
>   Screen.cs will make my code easier to read and understand.

I wouldn't use static members in this case, althought you could avoid it in this way:

```
class Title_Screen{
    //...
    public static ContentManager Content;
    Texture2D titleScreenPH;

    //...
    public static void Load(){
       titleScreenPH = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\TitleScreenPH");
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game{
    //...

    public Game1(){
        //...
        Title_Screen.Content = Content;
    }

    protected override void LoadContent(){
        //...
        Title_Screen.Load();
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

> I have a function now from resizing the image but it is only a manual
>   fix. I must input the correct width of the screen, is there a simple
>   way to check the screen height and width?

Yes you can get the screen size from the [`GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.presentationparameters%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) property:

```
int screenWidth = graphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth;
int screenHeight = graphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight;
```

Comment: I still need to use a static for `titleScreenPH` to say that it's useable. It does work but is there a way to automatically fit the image to the full screen? I have now edited the code to be up to date.